# Exporting Makehuman.js Three.js using THREE.OBJExporter

Tags: three.js, exporter, makehuman

I am using https://github.com/makehuman-js/makehuman-js

The example exports the mesh from the source. So I am trying to get it from the scene with where it is changed.

When I try to export my scene to an obj file it is empty:

```
     var objscene = new THREE.OBJExporter().parse( self.scene );
     var output = JSON.stringify( objscene, null, 2 );               
     saveAs (new Blob([output], {type : 'text/plain;charset=utf-8'} ), 'Avatar.obj');
```

I can count the objects in the scene.  There are four.

```
 var scene_size = app.scene.children.length; 
     var i = 0;
     while(i < scene_size){ 
        alert(app.scene.children[i]) 
        i = i + 1;
    }
```

However they have no names so I add a name to my main human object.

```
// HUMAN
this.human = new makehuman.Human(this.resources);
this.human.name = 'human';
```

So now I can retrieve the name of the object named human.

```
     var scene_size = app.scene.children.length; 
     var i = 0;
     while(i < scene_size){ 
        var thisone = app.scene.children[i]
        alert(thisone.name) 
        i = i + 1;
     }
```

So, I can demonstrate the objects exist.  I will assign names to the other objects later.  What I cannot understand is why my export is empty.  The file is 1kb in size and there is only "" in it when I open it in my editor.

Any insight would be appreciated.  I've been pounding it for a week and I am at a loss...  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`OBJExporter.parse()` does not return a JSON object. So it makes no sense to use `JSON.stringify()` in this context. Have a look at the actual output in this [example](https://threejs.org/examples/#misc_exporter_obj) (you will see it's just a plain string).

In any event, I recommend to use `GLTFExporter` instead since `glTF` is the [recommended format](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#manual/en/introduction/Loading-3D-models) of `three.js`. You can use code snippets from the following example for your own project.

https://threejs.org/examples/#misc_exporter_gltf

Comment: I'll give this a try yet I was hoping to export in the obj format.  I would like to export in obj, dae and glTF...

Comment: I wonder why this is... the actual makehuman model is imported from a JSON file: /data/models/human_full_size.json

Comment: I guess it's in `three.js` JSON format. You can create such an output if you just call `.toJSON()` of an `Object3D` like a scene.

Comment: I have tried a number of things including .toJSON().  I can see the object and it appears to be an array of all the available entities in Makehuman.  So, it's upon me to figure how to get what I want.  I was hoping that I would be able to export what was displayed in the viewport.  I'm not sure if any of this will export nicely in any format.  I will continue to dig until I find a way to make it work but it doesn't look like there will be a straight forward way of doing it..  Thanks for your input. I'll update this post when I find an answer.

Comment: I wonder why when using gui.dat to transform the mesh why when we export we get the base model and not a mesh with the transforms...

Comment: I guess it's better to create a new thread than posting more questions in this one. Don't forget to include a live example for debugging. In this way, it's way easier to provide useful feedback.